# Make local home KVM guests accessible via public IPv4 addresses/subnet

Tags: networking, wireguard, mikrotik-routeros

I have a physical Linux server at home with multiple KVM guests (Debian 12 Bookworm). I also have access to an IPv4 subnet + ASN and want to make the KVM guests accessible via these public IPs so I (and others) can communicate with them world-wide.

From my internet provider (Deutsche Telekom AG) I get a single unique dynamic IPv4 address without NAT, so I don't need to share my IP address with other people while I am connected. On re-connection a new IPv4 address is assigned. As modem and router I use a FritzBox 7530.

I already tried WireGuard but had problems with MTU/MSS. Also for the client IP addresses it will only show me the local network addresses, not the real public IP addresses.

I also thought about MikroTik, but I don't really understand how to connect two virtual MikroTik routers (if I even need two) together and then make the subnets available for the KVM guests.

Comment: Your objective is unclear to me. Do you have a single dynamic public IPv4 on which you NAT and want to know how to forward certain incoming connections on this address to the respective backend/guest? Or do you have a larger IPv4 subnet from which you seek to route a unique IPv4-Adress to each of your guests?

Comment: If I understand correctly:
- your home network has a single dynamic IPv4 connection;
- you have access to a IPv4 subnet that is located somewhere else in the network (externally to your home network);
- and you want addresses from that subnet to be forwarded to VMs on your home server?
In that case, you must have a device that is **physically located** in that IPv4 subnet, and create a tunnel between that device and your server (there are different software options to do this).

Comment: @Gamification: A single dynamic IPv4 address without NAT being required. The larger subnet can be announced anywhere (but not directly from my home internet).

Comment: Where are you announcing the IPv4 subnet at the moment? I'm assuming your BGP setup is somewhere else than the VM host?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I would order a virtual server at any hoster which offers BGP, Vultr for instance.

Answer (score 0):

> @u1686_grawity I would order a virtual server at any hoster which offers BGP, Vultr for instance.

In that case, if you announce BGP at one place but want to use the addresses at another, then that inherently requires some kind of tunnel.

Doesn't really matter what kind of tunnel – it could be WG or GRE or IPIP (SIT) or L2TP or OpenVPN, as long as you have IP inside IP, the result is the same.

However, in your case, it sounds like WireGuard will be the easiest choice as it has more automatic roaming, i.e. the BGP VM won't need to be manually updated with the new host IP address.

Note that if you use WireGuard with wg-quick, you should specify `Table=` to opt out of the default routing setup that wg-quick usually does.

> I already tried WireGuard but had problems with MTU/MSS

That's not a WireGuard-specific problem; all tunnels will result in reduced MTU (due to the extra IP header and other overhead), and most tunnels will have such problems if a) you block ICMP, b) the remote client or server that you're talking to blocks ICMP, or c) full moon.

Some tunnels, such as OpenVPN, try to use IP-level fragmentation (splitting an inner packet across two outer packets), but that leads to lower performance...not to mention networks that block IP fragments.

Probably the best workaround is to apply TCP MSS clamping right before packets enter the tunnel interface, so that both peers negotiate a MSS that fits through the tunnel. But, still, make sure you do not block ICMP 'Destination Unreachable' so that Path MTU Discovery would have some chance of working – especially for non-TCP-based protocols.

Reducing the MTU of your servers' network interfaces to the MTU of the tunnel would also have the effect of appropriately reduced TCP MSS (as the host will directly calculate it off the MTU it sees), but that's a lot of manual config to achieve the same thing as a single iptables 'TCPMSS' rule.

> Also for the client IP addresses it will only show me the local network addresses, not the real public IP addresses.

That's also not a WireGuard issue; that's an issue with the way you set up routing (or lack thereof). If you see the tunnel host's IP address as the "client" IP address, that means you've enabled SNAT (masquerade) in iptables.

Don't do SNAT. Instead, use **policy routing** as the recommended method to get response packets routed back through the tunnel (according to their 'source address').

> I also thought about MikroTik, but I don't really understand how to connect two virtual MikroTik routers (if I even need two) together and then make the subnets available for the KVM guests.

While that's technically doable, I would say the only reasons to use a RouterOS VM would be a) for consistency if you ran it alongside *physical* Mikrotik routers (but it sounds like you don't), or b) if you just prefer the configuration style.

Beyond that, RouterOS has nothing magic that would help you in this situation – it just does regular routing, regular BGP, etc. – so any basic routing setup you can do in RouterOS can just as easily be done on regular Linux. (And it'll likely be easier to do it directly on the VM host than on a separate VM.)

> Say I have 2+1 public IPv4s tunneled to the hosts single IPv4 address, how can I bind two of them to to guests and one (the +1) to the host?

There are several possible configurations; for example:

1. On the BGP router, statically route the entire x.y.z.0/24 via the tunnel interface.
2. On the home VM host, assign the whole /24 to the bridge interface that all your VMs are on – e.g. add x.y.z.1/24 to the vmbr0 interface.
3. On the VMs, configure addresses from the /24 as if it were a local subnet (because after step 2 it indeed is).

This would be the simplest method; you could even remove the original "internal" addresses that vmbr0 had previously.

You can split up the /24 at any point; e.g. if you have four separate bridge interfaces on the same VM host, in step 2 you could instead assign a /26 each (add x.y.z.1/26 to vmbr0, then x.y.z.65/26 to vmbr1, etc).

Another method would be to route individual IP addresses:

1. Same as above.
2. On the home VM host, assign a single address as a /32 to any interface. (Often this is done using the 'lo' loopback interface.)
3. On the two VMs, do the same and assign an address as a /32 to some interface – but keeping the existing internal address as well.
4. On the host, add static routes for each VM /32 `via` that VM's internal address.

Using /32's has the slight advantage in that it lets you use even the all-zeros and all-ones addresses (i.e. x.y.z.0 and x.y.z.255).

In *all* of the above methods, if the VM host runs Linux then you will need "policy routing" rules to direct return traffic back through the tunnel:

1. Add a default route (0.0.0.0/0) via the tunnel interface, to a separate routing table (e.g. table 2).

   ```
   manual: ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 2
   wg-quick: Table=2
   ```
2. Add a policy rule (via `ip rule`) so that packets *from* your new /24 select table 2.

   ```
   ip -4 rule add from x.y.z.0/24 lookup 2
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I still do not understand is how I could use GRE or IPIP when I only have one dynamic IPv4 address at home. For me it seems that only something like WireGuard would be possible in that case, as I do need to tunnel multiple public IPv4s at multiple guests at the local host.

Comment: Why do you think GRE would be different from WireGuard in that regard? Both of them are tunnels that fundamentally work the same way – both tunnel IP inside IP – so the number of IP addresses you have at home doesn't matter for either.

Comment: Because I need to distinguish. Say I have 2+1 public IPv4s tunneled to the hosts single IPv4 address, how can I bind two of them to to guests and one (the +1) to the host?

Comment: a) You assign one IP address as a /32 on one of the host's network interfaces, route the other two /32's to the VM interfaces; or b) You assign the entire /24 to the host's "VM bridge" and set up DHCP; or c) ...basically, once they're routed via the tunnel, you can treat them as local IPs. Still, that doesn't tell me why you think it's only possible with WireGuard but not with e.g. IPIP or GRE. Such things have been done for decades before WireGuard existed – was kind of the whole purpose of GRE, even.

Comment: Okay. I did now setup bird and successfully announced the /24 on a Vultr VPS. Now I need to find out how I can setup a permanent GRE tunnel to make the /24 usable on the local host and its guests. Unfortunately for me all of this is a bit complicated.

Comment: To be clear, the point was not that you *should* use GRE – in your case WireGuard will actually deal with dynamic IP better (and of course provides encryption) – the point was that they all fundamentally work the same way; the routing and the "policy routing" and everything else is going to be practically the same. (MTU issues as well.)